# How to set a value in the child class when extending a parent class

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have 2 classes:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ClassA {
    private Integer id;
    private String created_at;
}
```

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ClassB extends ClassA {
    private Boolean yesNo;
    private Commit commit;
}
```

I expect `ClassB` to have all fields from `CLassA`. Now I initiate a `ClassB` and try to assign values to it:

```
ClassB classB = new ClassB();
classB.setCreated_at("01/01/2023");
System.out.println(classB);
```

but there is no `created_at` value in classB, why? How can I set `created_at` in `classB` without redefining all `ClassA` fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
@Data
@ToString(callSuper = true)  // default implementation in @Data does not do this
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public static class ClassB extends ClassA {

    private Boolean yesNo;
    private String commit;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define ClassA's fields using `protected`. so they will be inherited in the child classB. you can also use the `@Setter` annotation to define the setter methods or just manually define them yourself. if you need the getter methods too, you should use `@Getter` annotation.

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
public class ClassA {
    protected Integer id;
    protected String created_at;
}
```